# How to design the CNF file from a given feature model?

Tags: cnf, software-product-lines

I met a problem in designing the **CNF** (conjunctive normal form) file from a given feature model. For example, there is a general feature model in SPL.

```
   A
 / | \
B  C  D
```

- **A, B, C, and D** are 4 features.
- **B** is a mandatory sub-feature of **A**
- **C** and **D** are two optional sub-features of **A**.

How can I write the CNF file of above constraints? Any help is appreciated!

Maybe the CNF file looks like the following form,

```
c 1 A
c 2 B
c 3 C
c 4 D
p cnf 4 X
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed format already looks similar to the DIMACS format. In this format the file contains a line for each clause of the CNF.

To my knowledge in dimacs format your model would look like this (the `// ...` are not part of the clauses or the dimacs format, but rather are there for clearification):

```
... // your lines go here
-1 2 0 // A implies B
-2 1 0 // B implies A
-3 1 0 // C implies A
-4 1 0 // D implies A
```

The trailing 0 serves as end of line or end of clause.
The first two lines translates from `A ↔ B`. Since it is the same as `A → B ^ B → A` You can check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_model) on how the semantics of a feature model translate into logical formulas.

Also there are several tools to create a cnf out of a given feature model.
For instance [FeatureIDE](http://featureide.github.io) lets you create a feature model via a GUI and later you are able to export it in dimacs format. This format enables you to use several other tools such as SAT4J to work with your model.

EDIT: I wonder what you mean exactly by SPL?

Comment: I know your meanings, but I think that the constraint `A implies B` should be represented as `-1 2 0` (i.e., **A -> B** equals **not A or B**). Similarly, `B implies A` should be represented as `-2 1 0`. Besides, FeatureIDE seems quite good, is it developed by your team?

Comment: thanks you are totally right with the constraints! No I'm not a part of the team, I just use it.

Comment: SPL means Software Product Line.